# Remove rows within a multi index dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a MultiIndex dataframe and the structure looks like below:

```
Instrument Date CHIMUCOPP
Field

0 2013-08-15 387564
1 2013-09-15 457847
2 2013-10-15 406708
```

[see columns type here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSOJR.png)

It looks like there are two rows of gap from the column index to the first value. But they seems doesn't belong to row index?
[It looks like this in csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD3bB.png)
I have tried a couple of methods including

```
df.drop('Field', axis=0)
```

But the name 'Field' is not the index name

1. How do i remove the 2 unnecessary rows below the columns names
2. How do i remove the 'Instrument' text

Answer (score 0):

`'Field'` is the name of you `index` and `'Instrument'` is the name of your `columns`.  The spacing is to make the names readable.  You probably want to remove those names with

```
df.rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Comment: but i got an error: TypeError: Must pass list-like as `names`.

Comment: @W_YY this is specific to your data. I can’t do anything without you providing sample data. Read [mcve] for an idea of what to do.